# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, linq

The error is :

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have tried many solutions find on Google search and even here but without success.

I have tried with :

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, 
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
```

But on the page I have error on this line because Linq not working :

```
string ns = string.Join(",", (from co in colorList select "?").ToList());
```

The `.dll` exists on the server:

[image]

My web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**#Edit 01**
[image]

**#Edit 02**
[image]

Comment: Try to add LINQ as a NuGet package.

Comment: Why all those assemblies are present in `compilation` section? What approach have you taken to add the reference of `System.Data.Linq.dll`? Did you do `Add Reference` from solution explorer?

Comment: The LINQ package provided in the NuGet package manager is actually `System.Linq` and not `System.Data.Linq` @Oxoron

Comment: @nbokmans thank you I ihae tried and I have this error 'System.Linq' already includes a dependency defined for 'System.Collections'.

Comment: Could you create an answer and accept it please?

Answer (score 2):

This error may be due to DLL version mismatch. Try to delete bin folder and rebuild the application.

Comment: Thanks but in application I don't have Bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding it via the `Add References` dialog instead of manually adding the DLL?

You can do that by expanding your project/solution folder in Visual Studio, selecting `References`, right clickting that and selecting `Add Reference`.

After that, select the `Assemblies` option in the menu and search for `System.Data.Linq`. Select the checkbox and press `OK` to add `System.Data.Linq` to your project.

[image]

Comment: @Thank I have tried without success, please see **#Edit 01** in my first question.

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq does your server have `.NET framework 4` installed and the application pool your site is running is is using `ASP.net 4.0` ?

Comment: You can framework version by going to `regedit.exe` (Windows key + R) and going here: `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework`

Comment: Thanks, please see **#Edit 02** in my first question-

Answer (score 0):

**#Edit 03**

Solved, I need change :
[image]

to:

[image]