# nUnit could not load System.Data.Linq

Tags: c#, nunit

I have an nUnit 3.11.0 project that targets Core 2.1. I am running into an exception on one of my tests that says

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.

The method works when running the application; it is the nUnit Core 2.1 that is not finding Linq. I tried to add a reference directly as a NuGet as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45368107/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-linq-version-4-0-0-0) post, but I can only find System.Linq (which didn't resolve the issue), and the post I was referencing seems to be a completely different issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an nUnit 3.11.0 project that targets Core 2.1.

That's not correct. From your post it seems the main project targets .Net Full Framework 4.0 and if the project for which you are setting up this test project targets framework 4.0 then your test project should as well target the same framework.

Comment: This is my first time using nUnit, and I agree. My project targets 4.5.2. The nUnit project seems to only target .NET Core. Perhaps there are multiple nUnit libraries and I just downloaded the wrong one? I've tried going to Install other frameworks from the Target framework drop-down, but this just brings me to the MS .NET page, and I obviously already have the 4.5.2 installed.